# How to get sum of two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

and want to sum its index value in Outer array as

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 11
)
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 10
)
```

for this what I'am doing

```
 $sum_inhale=array();
 foreach($x_inhale as $k=>$sub_array)
 { 
    foreach($sub_array as $id => $val)
    {
        $sum_inhale[$id] += $val; //<---Error occured here
    }
 }
 print_r($sum_inhale);
```

But I am getting notice also **Why?**

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined offset: 0</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/Report.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 463</p>

<p>Backtrace:</p>

<p style="margin-left:10px">
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\newyogapanel\application\controllers\Report.php<br />
Line: 463<br />
Function: _error_handler 
</p>


<p style="margin-left:10px">
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\newyogapanel\index.php<br />
Line: 315<br />
Function: require_once 
</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sum_inhale[$id]` is empty on the first loop, that's why you can't add numbers to it. Add this right before that line:

```
if (!isset($sum_inhale[$id])) $sum_inhale[$id] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_column()` with `array_sum()`:

```
foreach($x_inhale as $ind => $ar){
    $res[] = array_sum(array_column($x_inhale,$ind));
}
print_r($res);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nvGKZ)**

Comment: for more than two indexes in the inner array, the loop executes total length of the inner array

Comment: @VipinChoubey, you've provided defined input data and concrete desired output. That means your answer was unclear since the first second.